# Size of a request header field exceeds server limit

Tags: php, json, header

I am getting the following error again and again .. and I am not able to figure out what is wrong! All I did was that i copied and pasted the code from developers.facebook.com, and changed the app id and fb secrey key which i have crossed out for these questions!

The error is:

Bad Request
**Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.
Size of a request header field exceeds server limit.
Referer
/n**

The code is as given below:

```
                <?php
            define('FACEBOOK_APP_ID', 'xxxxx');
            define('FACEBOOK_SECRET', '2ab5cxxxxxxxxxx89a');

            function parse_signed_request($signed_request, $secret) {
              list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

              // decode the data
              $sig = base64_url_decode($encoded_sig);
              $data = json_decode(base64_url_decode($payload), true);

              if (strtoupper($data['algorithm']) !== 'HMAC-SHA256') {
                error_log('Unknown algorithm. Expected HMAC-SHA256');
                return null;
              }

              // check sig
              $expected_sig = hash_hmac('sha256', $payload, $secret, $raw = true);
              if ($sig !== $expected_sig) {
                error_log('Bad Signed JSON signature!');
                return null;
              }

              return $data;
            }

            function base64_url_decode($input) {
                return base64_decode(strtr($input, '-_', '+/'));
            }

            if ($_REQUEST) {
              echo '<p>signed_request contents:</p>';
              $response = parse_signed_request($_REQUEST['signed_request'], 
                                               Facenook_Secret);
              echo '<pre>';
              print_r($response);
              echo '</pre>';
            } else {
              echo '$_REQUEST is empty';
            }
            ?>
```

Comment: `Facenook_Secret` in the last if block? Face **n** ook?

Comment: I've seen this problem while on PayPal's website as well. Not sure what causes it, but I'm not the only one who's had that problem. The only suggestion I've seen while researching that problem was to clear your cache and cookies. Not a very good solution...

Comment: Clearing the Cache didnt help :(

Comment: 2 things, one of which that comes to mind when I tried using `sha256` on one server was that it did not properly execute all functions in one of my scripts; may be non-supportive? 2) Silly question maybe, but `Facenook_Secret` is that a deliberate typo?

Comment: i changed it to facebook yet the same results

Comment: You may have to post any other `relevant code`, so that others may be able to help you better, if there is any.

Comment: See if this link helps at all and Google your entire error message, there's a LOT out there. http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/871331

Comment: Just as @Travesty3 said, it `may` be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error doing some SHA2 hashing in javascript, after some code changes, on a previously working site.  This error was displayed by the default Android "Internet" browser on a Galaxy S3.  The Firefox mobile browser exhibited different incorrect behavior.  I did not identify the specific problem in code, but going to the settings for the "Internet" app, clearing the cache, and clearing all the *application* data, finally made this error go away.  The Firefox mobile browser corrected itself after some refreshing.